# Custom cytoscape layout with defined node positions and wo/ edges

Tags: cytoscape

Is there a way to use a custom layout in cytoscape desktop where I just define the position of the nodes? Furthermore the desired layout won't have any edges.

Specifically, I want to use a tSNE embedding as a layout in cytoscape desktop. Seem's to be possible with cytoscape.js:
https://medium.com/plotly/exploring-and-investigating-network-relationships-with-plotlys-dash-and-dash-cytoscape-ec625ef63c59

Thanks in advance!
Chris

Comment: Hi Chris.  Are asking about cytoscape desktop or cytoscape.js.  If you are asking about the desktop, the answer is definitely "yes".  In fact, with clusterMaker2, when you visualize the t-SNE, there is an option to copy the X,Y positions to the network, in essence doing exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi @ScooterMorris! I am asking about cytoscape desktop (I also updated my question accordingly), so I have the answer - great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Chris.  Just as an FYI, the latest version of clusterMaker2 now supports doing UMAP also....

Comment: Hi Scooter, good to know :) thanks a lot for your support!